# Directly connecting jaeger client to remote collector using kafka as intermediate buffer

Tags: apache-kafka, opentracing, jaeger

I am trying to connect to jaeger collector which uses Kafka as intermediate buffer.
Here are my doubts could any one please point to some docs .

QUESTION
  1. How to connect to collector by skipping agent and use kafka as intermediate buffer.Please provide me command or configuration
  2. Whats the configuration for kafka to connect to particular host.When I tried to use below command its still pointing to localhost and failing
    **docker run  -e SPAN_STORAGE_TYPE=kafka jaegertracing/jaeger-collector:1.17**

````
         ```{"level":"fatal","ts":1585063279.3705006,"caller":"collector/main.go:70","msg":"Failed to init storage factory","error":"kafka: client has run out of available brokers to talk to (Is your cluster reachable?)","stacktrace":"main.main.func1\n\tgithub.com/jaegertraci```
````

3. Please provide me some sample example so that I can go through,...